# How to extract content from sign using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

My content is a string like this:`whoad123@@${studentA.math1.math2}dsafddasfd${studentB.math2.math3}`,now I want to extract the content `studentA,studentB` which is in the braces and before the first pot(${**}).What's wrong with my code?

```
static java.util.regex.Pattern p1=java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\*\\$\\{\\w+\\}");
private static String getStudentName(String expression) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    java.util.regex.Matcher m1= p1.matcher(expression);
    while(m1.find()) {
        String param=m1.group(1);
        stringBuffer.append(param.substring(2,param.indexOf("\\.")) + ",");
    }
    if(stringBuffer.length()>0){
        return stringBuffer.deleteCharAt(stringBuffer.length()-1).toString();
    }
    return  null;
}
```

Comment: Use `\${(\w+)` - escape the backslashes. Result in capture group. `\\*` matches `*` literally and matching `}` seems unnecessary. No part of your string resembles `*${a}`

Comment: My result is null

Comment: Please revise your code. See working [tio.run sample here](https://tio.run/##dVBdS8MwFH1uf8Wl7CGlGtx8sxamojLYRJg@WR9i04/MtClJuimjv31maTs/mIGbC@fce85JVmRNTlf0fbdjZS2khpUBcKMZxzLN0w@8IDopUhm6//CPROtUVqHr1s0bZwkknCgFC8Iq2LpODypNtGlrwSiUhkJLLVmVv7wCkbny95NOxirCoSPAikMEXhyP4niL4ngT@F74d0x1zcxtCkHoeHI@nY62Sjc0rfQVLokuxvaetFSRjFKiMnoYuO4oe5@3Rv0g378K6r5HA4ITUdaMp8gGPDnAi@f502w@e7j1vzP2X2ce3PVokMM9grr4vjXeFEYWUE9hI0GRv/8ZMMdxnOWn0mmJRaNxbbY0r5B313DeyV@AB8HghHMpmhqd@Ua5386EBGS2gJkY49C0y@j3@I1oKo18QwXBYGt34bj3/X7JujJT3rEA7EeA1rXVuq27230B)

Comment: @ctwheels you have to escape the curly brace `{` also. The correct regex is `\$\{(\w+)`.

Comment: @CB_Ron thanks for that - I had that in the tio sample, failed to add it to my original regex. Too late no to update my comment.

Comment: @ctwheels,@CB_Ron.Thank you for your example.From your example,I have already get the content in ${**} like \$\{(.*?)\} ,studentA.math1.math2,studentB.math2.math3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\$\{([^{}.]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/27X8PQ/2)

Declare in Java as

```
static java.util.regex.Pattern p1=java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^{}.]+)");
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^{}.]+                  any character except: '{', '}', '.' (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getStudentName(String expression) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(?<student>\\w+)\\.[^\\}]+\\}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        names.add(matcher.group("student"));
    }

    return String.join(",", names);
}
```

See demo in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bC3CYG/1)